# ReactDomServer vs Next.js SSR

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, react-dom-server

`ReactDomServer` and `Next.js` both support server side rendering. Besides developer experience, how are they different?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. Your question isn't a good fit as asked. You need to do the research to understand the differences, then ask a specific question. SO is supposed to be about giving detailed answers that solve a specific question and yours will result in generalized answers. You might get better answers in one of the server-oriented SE sites.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.